# i want to delete duplicate values rows including orignal in excel sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

i have a sheet of almost 15k data in that like firstname lastname city address phone no. i want to delete rows of duplicate  values  in phone no. column and original value .

example:

```
firstname| lastname|address1| city | phone no.|
  a          a1       xzc      ada     1234
  b          b1       qwe      asd     0987
  c          c1       jlk      oiu     4567
  b          bb       asd      ewr     0987
  a          aa       ojh      bnv     1234
```

i want to delete duplicate values (0987 , 1234) and complete rows including original value. how i can do this ? i am try through if and ifcount function but failed. remember i have 15k data in sheet.

help me for solving this problem.

Comment: when there is a duplicate entry, do you want to keep the first instance, that last instance, or some other instance?  To actually delete the data you cannot do it with formulas alone.  If you want to generate another list of non duplicate data that is another story.

Answer (score 0):

As you want all records deleted if there is a duplicate, it would have to be either a VBA script or a two-step process.

For the two-step process, create a function in column F
=COUNTIF(E:E, E2)

This will count all occurrences of that phone number.

Then filter column F to include any numbers other than 1 (unselect 1). Select all remaining rows and delete them.

---

Original Answer:
You can use Excel's built-in remove duplicates function.

Select your whole sheet, then under the Data tab there is a Remove Duplicates option (alternatively, press Alt then A then M). Select just the "phone no." column and press OK.

Excel will automatically remove any rows that had a duplicate phone number (leaving only one row with that number)

Comment: yeh i know i want to delete original also .. can you help me ?

Comment: and according to you instruction that will not delete duplicate values rows. he just delete value in selected column.

Comment: Remove Duplicates does delete the entire row. It is just asking which columns to check for duplicates, not which columns to delete from.